# Adding windows boot record to Grub

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I am trying to get windows to appear in my grub options so I can bot into it.
Here is my drive below.

```
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
    sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
    |-sda4   8:4    0 200.8G  0 part    -WINDOWS 
    |-sda2   8:2    0   3.7G  0 part [SWAP] FOR ARCH
    |-sda3   8:3    0   500M  0 part  - WINDOWS BACKUP
    `-sda1   8:1    0  93.1G  0 part  -ARCH LINUX
```

I added the info to the grub boot file

```
    $ sudo cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows 10" {
   set root='(hd0,4)'
   chainloader +1
}
```

Arch Linux and Arch Linux Advanced boot are still the only options in my grub? Can anyone help??

Comment: Did you also run `chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom` and then `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB, you should also run an analogue of

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

to actually generate the configurarion file from `/etc/grub.d`.

Comment: This worked. I also had to change my  set root='(hd0,4)' to  set root='(hd0,3)'.